# Страница не получает ответ с сервера

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Функция javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function ValidPhone() {
                        var re = /^\d{11}$/;
                        var myPhone = document.getElementById('brone_phone').value;
                        var valid = re.test(myPhone);
                        if (valid) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "mail.php",
                                type: "get",
                                data: {
                                    tnumber: myPhone
                                },
                                success: function (response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                },
                                error: function (xhr) {

                                }
                            });

                            $(".success_mod_overlay").css("display", "block");
                        } else {
                            redconnect.api.popup.open();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return valid;
                    }
        </script>
```

файл mail.php :

```
<?php
echo "OK";

?>
```

После вызова функции ValidPhone() всплывает пустой alert. Поделитесь соображениями, пожалуйста..

Comment: `url: "/mail.php",` - возможно так стоит?

Comment: success то срабатывает..

Comment: `success` - не зависит от пути, он вполне может быть не правильным. с какой страницы запускаете и где находится mail.php?

Comment: оба файла в одной директории

Comment: думаю, если бы путь до файла был неверным success бы не сработал

Comment: А вы проверьте, укажите несуществующий файл...

Comment: что в консоли после запроса? Допишите алерт в error. И type: 'get' можно не указывать, у аякс запросов он по-умолчанию гет.

Comment: вы смотрите на вкладке Сеть, что происходит с вашим запросом, а не алерты вставляйте